# Maps not displayed in real device

Tags: android, android-maps

I try with google maps application in developer site.
Generate api key and runs it in emulator smooth.
The problem is when I deploy it in real device it shows only grid checks.
I also generate release key and pasted the key in layout mapview.
Whats wrong with that.
Kindly help me with brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is the data connection. Has the phone got a good reception? Does the Google Maps app work on the phone?